# update/edit a record in django using forms

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms

I am new to django and have seen few answers about update/edit record in django forms. that scenerio's are not working for me. below is my code snippets.

Here is my models :

```
class author(models.Model):
   author_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   book_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   content = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

forms.py:

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
      model = author
      fields = ['author_name', 'book_name', 'content']
```

views.py :

```
def update_record(request,id):
    if request.POST:
       book_form = AuthorForm(request.POST)
       if book_form.is_valid():
         author = AuthorForm.objects.get(pk=id)
         book_form = AuthorForm(request.POST, instance = author)
         book_form.save()  
         return HttpResponse('Update_record')
   else:
       book = AuthorForm.objects.get(pk = id)
       book_form = AuthorForm(instance=book)

   return render(request, 'update.html', {'form':book_form })
```

application level url:

```
 urlpatterns = [

   path('crud_4/', views.update_record),

]
```

project level url :

```
  urlpatterns = [

   path('crud_url/(?P<id>\d+)/$', include('myapp_2.urls')),

 ]
```

template:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Update</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="" method="post">
  {{form.as_p }}
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: "not working" is a totally useless description of a problem. Please edit your question to explain _exactly_ how it "doesn't work" - if you get an error, post the exact exception message AND the full traceback, else explains what happens (and how you checked it).

Comment: This being said, your code snippet is wrong on a couple of things, the first one being that you're using `AuthorForm` instead of `author` (which should be named `Author` by the way) to get your model instance. If that's really your code, it shiould indeed raise an `AttributeError`. If that's NOT really your code, please post the real code instead - debugging is painful enough already, we don't have time to play guessing games ;-)